# click-able div open in new window

Tags: jquery

Easy enough to make a div with a background image clickable:

```
$(".socialMedia").click(function(){
             window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
             return false;
        });
```

How can you make that open in a new window, its not using the anchor's target element, when I switch window.location to window.open i get an error. Is it possible?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.socialMedia').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'), '');
});
```

In this bit of JavaScript we are selecting all elements that have the `socialMedia` class. We then bind a callback function to each of these elements. This function defines one parameter, `e`, that represents the jQuery [Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) object.

Now, when a user clicks one of the `socialMeda` elements our callback function executes. First, the function uses the jQuery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to stop the browser from performing any default actions (e.g. go to a URL defined in a clicked link element). Then we use the [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) method to open our desired URL. We get this URL by finding the first link element within the `socialMedia` element that was clicked (just in case there are multiple links).

Comment: @jsummers- works perfect. So I am to assume that (e) and e.preventDefault is better than return false;? Could you explain the second part? I see we have "window.open" working and your using the selector :first to get the first link in the div? what does the , '' after ('href') do? Something to do with the target I think?

Comment: @hunter, I opted for `:first` because I don't know much about his markup.

Comment: @Dirty, I added more explanation to my answer.

Comment: @jsumners - I really appreciate it, and hate to be a dick but.... is event.preventDefault(); better than return false; and what about the '' after ('href') does that just go to the next element after target?

Comment: @Dirty, I provided you with links to plenty of documentation. The jQuery event.preventDefault() provides a cross browser solution to stopping the default browser action. And the empty string for the second parameter of window.open() is just to explicitly set an empty window name.

Comment: Sorry man. I appreciate your help. Some of us are just born stupid.